# Why is $\int(f+g)g^{\prime}dr\neq\int(f+g)dg$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $f(r)$ and $g(r)$ be some two functions of $r$.

Why is the integral $\int{\left[(f+g)\frac{dg}{dr}\right]dr}$

not equal

$\int{\left(f+g\right)dg}=f g+g^{2}/2$

I tried

$$f(r)=\sin r$$
and
$$g(r)=r^{2}+1$$

but the answer of the two integrals came different.

where

$\int{\left(f+g\right)dg}=1/2+r^2+r^{4}/2+\sin r+r^{2}\sin r$

but

$\int{\left[(f+g)\frac{dg}{dr}\right]dr}=r^2+r^{4}/2-2r\cos r+2\sin r$

Comment: Constant is missing.

Comment: It is not true that $\int f\,dg = fg$ in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int(f+g)g'dr = \frac{g^2}{2} + fg - \int f'gdr.$$

Comment: Where does the last term come from?

Comment: @MrDi Itegration by parts. You can check that both sides are equal by differentiating.